# MODX Revo snippet permissions

Tags: security, permissions, modx-revolution

Is there any way to change a snippet visibility not for Super Users?

Is there any way to deny snippet editing not for Super Users?

E. g. if the user is a member of Members group only I'd like to hide some snippets from him/her. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it. Or permit access to a snippet, or not. Anyone even slightly familiar with php having access to edit the contents of the snippet can do with your site all that he wants.

Comment: Is there any way to override the base class or implement the security class? For example, how trigger my own SecurityClass on some before_snippet_load event?

Comment: Do not quite understand what you mean by "my own SecurityClass".

Comment: I mean i there some way to run my custom code before some (if exists smth like this) 'snippet_load_event'.

Comment: Yes, but something common for all the snippets. Something universal.

Comment: In modx we have plugins for this purposes. No possibility to execution before snippets, but it is possible to be called when the page is loaded, and depending on the template run any code.